# xCode error building for iOS : The sandbox is not in sync with podfile.lock

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I'm building from Unity, with Google Play Game Services SDK and Firebase Analytics SDK.
So Unity creates the xcode project for me, even the podfile with the dependencies I'm needing.

I make my `pod install`, everything looks ok and generate everything it should. But when I open the `.xcworkspace` and build, I have the following error :

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock : No such file or Directory
diff: /Manifest.lock : No such file or Directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your  CocoaPods installation
```

I'm sorry to post this question again but I've been looking for hours trying every solutions I can find, multiple times, mixing them together... with no luck until now :

- First tried the obvious redoing `pod install`
- Tried `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`
- Tried to rebuild the iOS version, over the last one, on a clean directory...
- Tried to remove all pods directories/files and running `pod init` editing the pod file and running `pod install` after a first install, directly after building the project with Unity,
- Checked my `PODS_ROOT` that is set correctly to `${SRCROOT}` : which is the pods directory into my project, I can find `/../podfile.lock` and `/manifest.lock` from this directory
- Tried to update `CocoaPods`, checked I had the lastest version (1.1.1)

Looks like I tried so many other things since I spend hours on this with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I read too much about cocoapods and didn't pay enough attention to what was generated by Unity and Google Plugins.

It appears that google plugins, generate the podfile and install it themselves. There is no need of doing pod installs and so on. The misleading fact is that **with a Unity** generated project for iOS **you actually want to open the `.xcodeproj`** and not a `.xcworkspace`.